# call function in parent javascript from child window

Tags: javascript, jsp, window

I hava a javascript function which opens a new jsp window using `window.open(...);`
Also I have the `function passValues(value);`

In my child window I do some stuff and eventually i will pass values to my parent javascript like so:

```
window.opener.passValues(value);
```

When I try to use `'this'` in the function, it refers to `window.opener`.

This I don't want to happen.. I want that my this remains the this that it was before I called the `passValues function`.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in event handlers "this" refers to the function called. So is necesary to make a reference: `var self = this` inside the callback. And use "self" as "this"

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the function with `Function.prototype.call` or `Function.prototype.apply`.

```
window.opener.passValues.call( this, value );
```

That would invoke `.passValues` with the current value of `this`, to nail it down to the current `window` object, just call

```
window.opener.passValues.call( window, value );
```

---

`.call()` and `.apply()` both offer the option to set the value for the *this context variable` within the *function of invocation*.

---

Reference: [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: this still isn't the solution, because I call the function when i click a button..
When I'm in the passValues function the this is now the childwindow and I want it to be the javascript file

Comment: @user1345883: I'm afraid I don't understand that. `this` always refers to an `object` / *context. So What exactly do you mean with "the javascript file" ? You can pass any object-reference to `.call()` and `.apply()`, the `this` value will than refer this object within the invocation.

Answer (score 0):

In your child window, call the parent function with `call` or `apply` and pass the scope of your child window with `this`

```
window.opener.passValues.call(this, value);
```

or if you want to pass more than one argument, use apply

```
window.opener.passValues.apply(this, [value1, value2]);
```

However, if you call the parent function in the context of the child scope (this), you're able to access global variables of the child window with this.value, so passing the values might be obsolete.

Be aware that the value of `this` depends on the context of the function call itself... For example, if you call it from within an onclick handler of a link (BTW don't do that), `this` referes to the context of the link, not to the child `window`. Same when you call it from within a instantiated object (with `new`), `this` referes to the scope of the class and not to the child `window`. In doubt, replace `this` with that object, who's scope you want the function be called in.

```
 window.opener.passValues.call(window, value);
```